# difference between onViewRender and events to load events in full calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am using onViewRender to load events for my full calendar in an angular2 application.  using onViewRender is making multiple api calls to fetch events. can I use anything else than onViewRender in my template to load events. below is the problem im facing .

```
Put a <p-schedule (onViewRender)="testMethod($event)"> on your template. Add a method such as this to your component:

testMethod(e)
{
console.log(e);
}

You'll see that the method is called infinitely.
```

and below is my actual code

component.html

```
     <p-schedule [events]="events" [eventLimit] ="3" (onViewRender)="loadEvents($event)" 
    (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" 
     (onDayClick)="handleDayClick($event)" ></p-schedule>

component.ts

 loadEvents(e) {


    if (this) {
      let month = e.view.start._d.getMonth() + 2;
      let year = e.view.start._d.getFullYear();

      if (month == '13') {
        month = 1;
        year = year + 1;

      }

      this.userService.getGadgetsData(this.calendarInfo.id, "Calendar", month, year).subscribe(gadgetsData => {


         this.newEvents = gadgetsData.Data.Issues.map(function (o) {
          return o.Values.reduce(function (acc, _ref) {
            var Key = _ref.Key,
              Value = _ref.Value;
            return acc[Key] = Value, acc;
          }, {});
        });

        this.newEventsInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newEvents).split(this.eventField).join('eventDate'));

        this.calendarEvents = this.newEventsInfo.map(({ Key, Summary, eventDate, Created }) =>
          ({ title: Key + ': ' + Summary, start: eventDate, id: Key, tooltip: Summary }));

        this.eventsData = this.calendarEvents.map(function (o) {

          o.start = moment.utc(o.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          return o;

        });

         this.events = this.eventsData; // here is the code which replaces event list

      });
    }

  }
```

Replacing the events list triggers another onViewRender event, causing infinite loop.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2264 - i found some link related to this issue, but unable to fix this

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ show the standard ways to link your events to the calendar. Nowhere have I ever seen the suggestion to anyone to use viewRender - where did you get that idea? It's normal for the calendar to make a new request each time either the view type or the date changes though (although fullCalendar will try to cache data to minimise this) - the pattern is to only fetch the data actually needed at the time, as often users will not view many other date ranges anyway.

Comment: @ADyson - i got what u r saying. the problem is calendar is fetching infinite calls to api even without view type or date changes. i am not able to figure that part out. is there any around way to sort it in my code likegithub.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2264

Comment: well like I said, you should change your code entirely to use the approach suggested in the documentation to fetch events. It's not obvious from this code alone why it should be making infinite calls, but hopefully if you follow a recognised design pattern it should solve it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded ngprime from 2.0.3 to 2.0.0 and now it works fine. no more api calls.